# In an 8 circuit panel, why would I have 240v on some 20A breakers and 120v on others? And, I have 240v on one leg of a 30A breaker and 120v the other?

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I installed a new 8 circuit breaker panel in my garage. I installed (6) 20A breakers for lights, outlets, garage door openers and power tools; and (1) 30A breaker for my grinder pump, which requires 240v. 3 of the 20A breakers have 120V on the output and 3 have 240V. On 1 leg of the 30A breaker, it reads 240V and 120V on the other. When I turn on the 30A breaker, the grinder pump alarm goes off. I do have all of the ground wires and the neutrals on the same bus bar (is that a problem?). Even though this is a panel for my detached garage, this panel is a direct feed from the main shut-off breaker after the meter.

Comment: It sounds like some wires may be crossed but that is just a SWAG. Post some clear pictures of what you have and indicate your measuring and reference points.

Comment: Yes, please do [edit] in some pics of the wiring at the new panel and the supply point of the old panel. If you do so, you'll get explicit instructions on what to move where. Also, NO having the grounds & neutrals on the same buss bar in a subpanel violates NEC for the last 20 years, at least, probably _much_ longer than that.

Comment: Yes, and if you need to change browser or device, be sure to [register your account](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts) so you can log in from that other device.

Answer (score 11):

#### TL;DR SHUT THIS DOWN UNTIL YOU FIGURE IT OUT!

Turn off the feed breaker (i.e., the breaker in the main panel that feeds to this subpanel). Make sure that you have **no power at all** (i.e., hot to hot, hot to neutral, neutral to ground should all show 0V) before doing anything else.

This is **seriously dangerous**, and represents a small mixup, but with big consequences, that **should never happen**.

I think the core problem is that you have neutral and one of the hots swapped. The way things should work is that each hot is 120V to neutral and the hots are 240V to each other. A swap of neutral and one of the hots would result in one hot (the one that was swapped) being 120V to neutral and the other hot 240V to neutral and the two hots (one of which is really neutral) would have 120V between them. Any 120V devices on the 240V side will get zapped. Any 240V devices won't work (or will work marginally, as they are getting 120V instead of 240V) and any combination 120V/240V devices (e.g., typical clothes dryer) will just be wacky. **And all of it is dangerous.**

Hot and neutral swapped on a 120V receptacle is *bad*. I've found some of those in my house and fixed them. But that won't affect normal operation of a plugged in device - only when there is another problem added to the mix. Swapped at the panel? **Big problem.**

On top of that, while combining ground and neutral in a subpanel used to be OK, it has not been allowed on anything new for many years. In a situation where everything else is done correctly, combining neutral and ground at a subpanel doesn't really matter all that much. But since your neutral and a hot were swapped, now you have ground tied to one of your hots. Which is a really, really bad thing.

**How to fix it?**

- Start with the feed wires or cable at the main panel. You should have either 4 wires (hot, hot, neutral, ground) or 3 wires running through metal conduit (which functions as the ground). If the wires are in cable then you *must* use the standard coding of black/red = hot, white = neutral, bare (or green) = ground. If the wires are individual wires in conduit then you can't use a white wire as hot but you can mark a black wire with white tape on both ends to use it as neutral, but only if it is 4 AWG or larger. Once you have confirmed that the correct color wires are connected to the main panel (hots to breaker, neutral to neutral bar, ground to ground bar or (if it is a true main panel) neutral bar, then check the subpanel.
- The subpanel must have the wires connected the same way. Note that because this is a detached building you should have a disconnect. A disconnect can be a separate box, in which case it will typically only switch the hot wires and not neutral (and never ground). Or a disconnect can be a main breaker in a "main" panel used as a subpanel, or a backfed breaker in a subpanel. Again, hots to breaker, neutral to neutral bar, ground to ground bar.

If you find an "oops" - whether in the main panel, the subpanel, or a disconnect in between, fix it and then turn on and test carefully.

If you don't find anything wrong, **stop** and upload pictures showing both panels.

Answer (score 1):

One way get the result you describe would be to swap one of the live feeds  and the neutral feed

check that they all go to the correct place at both ends.